# Keywords limit in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, term-store, term-set, limitations, enterprise-keywords

[This article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/managed-metadata-service-capacity-and-performance) mentions a test value of 80,000 for Enterprise keywords.
[This article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-an-enterprise-keywords-column-to-a-list-or-library-314ce556-e4bf-4ef7-9939-6a1bedfc434a) mentions that keywords is just a non-hierarchical term set:

> SharePoint products collect the enterprise keywords into a single,
> non-hierarchical term set. You can find this special term set, which
> is named the Keywords set, by using the Term Store Management Tool.

[Software boundaries and limits for SharePoint 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/software-boundaries-and-limits) gives a supported limit of 30,000 items in a term set.

[image: supported limit]

What is the maximum number of keywords that can be used in SharePoint 2013?

Can this limit be modified?

**UPDATE**

As it turns out, there is no boundary or configuration setting for the number of keywords. It's just a recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supported limits define the tested value for a given parameter. The default values for these limits were defined by testing, and represent the known limitations of the product. Exceeding supported limits could cause unexpected results, significant performance degradation, or other detrimental effects.

Thresholds and supported limits guidelines are determined by performance. In other words, you can exceed the default values of the limits, but as you increase the limit value, farm performance and the effective value of other limits might be affected. Many limits in SharePoint Server 2013 can be changed. However, you should understand how changing a given limit affects other parts of the farm.

Reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/capacity-management-and-sizing-overview

Comment: Thank you, Julie!

Comment: If you think the reply is helpful,  you can mark it as answer.